# How to remove the space between hamburger icon lines

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code I'm trying to reduce the size of this hamburger icon to fit it in the corner but I'm stuck. Below are the HTML, CSS and JavaScript files. By reducing or increasing the  `margin` or `paddding` of the either `bg` of the icon or the lines itself doesn't seem to have any effect on the result. I want a solution so that I could decrease the size of the icon as a whole without effecting its components but if there is a solution which would effect the components would also work.

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
let menuOpen = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!menuOpen) {
    menuBtn.classList.add('open');
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
    menuOpen = false;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* body----------------------------------------------------------- */

body {
  background: #272727;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/* body-end-------------------------------------------------------- */


/* menu bg ---------------------------------------------------------*/

.menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 90%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  /* border: 3px solid #fff; */
}


/* menu bg-end --------------------------------------------------------*/


/* the-hamburger ------------------------------------------------------*/

.menu-btn__burger {
  width: 30px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255, 101, 47, .2);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn__burger::before,
.menu-btn__burger::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255, 101, 47, .2);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn__burger::before {
  transform: translateY(-16px);
}

.menu-btn__burger::after {
  transform: translateY(16px);
}


/* ANIMATION */

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger {
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
}

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
}


/* the-hamburger-end -----------------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>CSS Hamburger Animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <div class="menu-btn__burger"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried `padding: 0px;` and `margin: 0px` also tried resetting the height of the lines but it won't work. Also tried to reduce `font-size:`  but it won't work.

Comment: change your translations to plus and minus 6px - that's the height of your lines so if you don't want any space between them then that should do it

Comment: @Pete You mean transitions ?

Comment: no your before and after translations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `translateY` value for `:before` and `:after`

```
.menu-btn__burger::before {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.menu-btn__burger::after {
    transform: translateY(10px);
}
```